# Using CImg to fill in color using linear interpolation

Tags: c++, colors, interpolation, cimg

"Using CImg, write a program that constructs a square image and assigns a color to each corner. Using
linear interpolation, fill in and color each pixel in the square so that there is a smooth coloring across
the entire area of the square"

I have a hard time to understand how to pick a color for each corner, and fill in color for the square. Below is the code that I have, but it seems randomly place the color, and I cannot pick my own color. Below the code I have right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg/CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main() {
  //Create an empty image
  CImg<unsigned char> square(255, 255, 1, 3, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 255; j++){
          //Red
          square(i,j,0,0) = i; 
          //Green
          square(i,j,0,1) = j;
          //Blue
          square(i,j,0,2) = i;                
      }
  }

  //Display and save filtered image
  CImgDisplay disp(square); 
  while (!disp.is_closed())
      disp.wait();   
  square.save("squareInterpolation.bmp");  
}
```

Result from my code:
[image]

Result I wanted (ignore the white border):
[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: One question per question please!

Comment: Is your triangle supposed to have different coloured corners and interpolate a smoothly gradated fill colour? Or are you supposed to create a solid background and draw a solid coloured triangle on it by knowing the coordinates of the vertices?

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and remove the triangle part of the question and re-state it clearly as a new question in the light of my previous comment. Questions are free... answers too ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a better idea how to use CImg now.  I removed the second part about the triangle, and will create a new post for that question. Thanks again!

Comment: If you felt like up-voting either or both of my answers, that would be great ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your code isn't doing any interpolation - it is just assigning. Interpolation is where you know some values at the limits of an image and calculate the values in-between those known values (using a formula) to fill in the unknown values.

Actually, `CImg` will do interpolation for you and, IMHO, good engineers re-use and recycle well-tested code as it keeps costs down. So, the simplest solution is to create a 2x2 image of the red, green, blue and white corner points (the known values in the interpolation) and let `CImg` resize your image up to 255x255 using interpolation.

That could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

#define INTERPOLATION_LINEAR            3
#define INTERPOLATION_CUBIC             5

#define BOUNDARY_DIRICHLET              0
#define BOUNDARY_NEUMANN                1

int main() {
   // Create 2x2 image with Red, Green, Blue and White pixels
   CImg<unsigned char> image(2,2,1,3,0);
   image(0,0,0,0)=255;  // top-left is Red
   image(1,0,0,1)=255;  // top-right is Green
   image(0,1,0,2)=255;  // bottom-left is Blue
   image(1,1,0,0)=255;  // bottom-right is white
   image(1,1,0,1)=255;  // bottom-right is white
   image(1,1,0,2)=255;  // bottom-right is white

   // Let CImg do the interpolation for us - because smart engineers re-use well tested code
   CImg<unsigned char> result=image.resize(255,255,-100,-100,INTERPOLATION_LINEAR,BOUNDARY_DIRICHLET);

   // Save result image as NetPBM PNM - no libraries required
   result.save_pnm("result.pnm");
}
```

[image]

I guess that is not the way you are expected to do it, so I would combine that solution with a further one where I implemented the interpolation myself. Here is a formula you might use from the [Wikipedia article on Bilinear Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation).

[image]

That could be implemented to like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main() {
   // Create 256x256 image with Red, Green, Blue and White pixels
   CImg<unsigned char> image(256,256,1,3,0);
   image(0,0,0,0)=255;      // top-left is Red
   image(255,0,0,1)=255;    // top-right is Green
   image(0,255,0,2)=255;    // bottom-left is Blue
   image(255,255,0,0)=255;  // bottom-right is white
   image(255,255,0,1)=255;  // bottom-right is white
   image(255,255,0,2)=255;  // bottom-right is white

   // Fill inner area by interpolation
   for(int r=0;r<256;r++){                   // "r" for "row" 
      for(int c=0;c<256;c++){                // "c" for "column"
         for(int b=0;b<3;b++){               // "b" for "band" in my head
            float oneMinusX=(255-r)/255.0;
            float oneMinusY=(255-c)/255.0;
            image(r,c,0,b)=image(0,0,0,b)*oneMinusX*oneMinusY +
                     image(255,0,0,b)*oneMinusY*r/255.0 +
                     image(0,255,0,b)*oneMinusX*c/255.0 +
                     image(255,255,0,b)*r*c/(255.0*255.0);
         }
      }
   }

   // Save result image as NetPBM PNM - no libraries required
   image.save_pnm("result.pnm");
}
```